# I have prepared a file in ModelSim and saved it in a library named "work" and for graph I am not able to find my project under my saved library

Tags: modelsim

I have written the code and compilation was successful but when I go for simulation I am not able to find my project under the saved library and it is empty. I have tried to change the directory but also it is not resolved and tried to create a new library but my project is not getting saved in the library for simulation. Can anyone solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Change the directory first then compile. Not the other way.

Comment: I would recommend that you stop using the Altera examples directory inside the installation folder and make a folder for your own files on C drive. Also Print Screen has a keyboard key, so paste the clipboard output in, for example, "Paint", instead of using a camera.